# How to execute database insert do MariaDB using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, insert, mariadb

I have a problem inserting data into my database table. I'm using Python and MariaDB. Connection to database is open and tested, I'm able to query the database, but I can't nail the insert syntax. I've found two ways, but neither work.

```
insert = (
    "INSERT INTO ksiazka (ISBN, tytul, autor, rok_wydania, ilosc stron)"
    "VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
)
dane = (ISBN, tytul, autor, rok_wydania, ilosc_stron)
cursor.execute(insert, dane)
```

or this way:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ksiazka (ISBN, tytul, autor, rok_wydania, ilosc stron) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (ISBN, tytul, autor, rok_wydania, ilosc_stron))
```

When executing I get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py",
>   line 377, in cmd_query
>       raw_as_string=raw_as_string)
>   _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'stron)VALUES
>   ('12345678','wertvfdg','3','1243','213')' at line 1
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/jakub/PycharmProjects/biblioteka/sql_connector.py", line 57,
>   in 
>       cursor.execute(insert, dane)   File "C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor_cext.py",
>   line 264, in execute
>       raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)   File "C:\Users\jakub\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection_cext.py",
>   line 380, in cmd_query
>       sqlstate=exc.sqlstate) mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'stron)VALUES ('12345678','wertvfdg','3','1243','213')' at
>   line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column name has a space in it, then it needs special handling and you must escape it:

```
INSERT INTO ksiazka (ISBN, tytul, autor, rok_wydania, `ilosc stron`) ...
```

This is why spaces in column names are annoying and should be avoided.

Comment: I'll be damned! There is no space in that column name, it should be ilosc_stron, I corrected and it started working. Thank you for catching that. My editor was underlining the whole statement and I didn't see that there was no _ there.